# how i can share a report with data set to other user in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, olap-cube, power-bi-report-server

I have a report from power bi, which has a direct connection to the server to obtain the data (analisys services). To access the data from my account I use the on premises data gateway, which works correctly and I can view the data in the web app. The problem appears when the report to another user (both having the pro account). From the account of the other user you can see that a report was shared, but when you open it the following error appears: "Error executing the query because the cube or some internal structures have not been processed (or do not exist)" .Also grant owner permissions to the cube to the user in question. Any clue where it might be failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was easy but finding it was difficult. The issue was that even though you had assigned the role in the cube to the user who wanted to share the report, you had not given them read permission (assuming the role had already been assigned). It is a basic problem but if you are a beginner in analysis services it can get complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should Map usernames for this connection.
Go to settings -> Manage gateways
Under your gateway cluster you should have your data source (if not you can add a new one and it's quite straight forward to set up, just choose analysis services, write in database name of server and credentials) and then you should go to Users tab.
There you can see Map usernames where you need to Replace the account to which you want to share with an account that has permissions in SSMS.
For example you want to share to example@elpmaxe.com and you have granted permissions in SSMS to user named example.elpmaxe, so in map usernames you would replace example@elpmaxe.com with example.elpmaxe